# Phantomjs to take a screenshot of site as rendered on iphone

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I would like to use phantomjs to take a screenshot of a webpage like if is rendered on iphone.

I use this:

```
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A523 Safari/8356.25';
page.viewportSize = { width: 320, height: 480 };


page.open(address, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
        phantom.exit(2);
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            page.clipRect = { top: 0, left: 0, width: 320, height: 480 };
            page.render(output);
            phantom.exit(3);
        }, 200);
    }
});
```

But doesn't seems to work...

Comment: What is the result?  Just a normal looking screenshot?

Comment: the result is a screenshot of the page with the dimension specified: 320x480.

Comment: This not is rendered as on my iphone...

Comment: Looking for an answer too! Any progress?

Comment: I have not tried recently. However the problem is that if the site is responsive, phnatomjs render it as mobile, otherwise it render only small part of site as viewport settings, but not resize it as in mobile.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Responsive design testing with PhantomJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23914538/responsive-design-testing-with-phantomjs)